# Process a request and then pass it on to a different URL and let that page respond

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httprequest

I'm able to specify a URL that Google sends a request to after a sale is made on my site via Google Wallet. Lets call that URL A. What I'd like to do instead, however, is have the request go to URL B, have URL B do some things, and then send along the exact request on to URL A. URL A would then repond, and this response needs to get back to the original caller (Google in this case).

The original request could possibly include POST values.

Comment: Assume the request needing to be forwarded is not a POST?

Comment: Can't make that assumption

Comment: If this originates as a POST then and you need to forward it along exactly as received you'll end up needing to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: are there other parts to the request that i may need to worry about? i was hoping to be able to easily pass on the request unchanged, rather than having to reconstruct an equivalent request.

Comment: Hard to say.  Not sure what Google is looking for in the response.  Reading your question after your updates I am a little confused.  If all Google is looking for is a 200 OK response there should be really no need to have URL A "respond" (the way you describe what you want URL A to do would result in it "responding" to URL B" anyway, not Goole, true?).

Comment: @ficuscr -- might have confused you but your initial comment seems to be the solution -- using curl. unless deyes has a simpler solution, you can post yours and i'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to forward the POST you receive to another URL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
```

Note the use of [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to create a URL-encoded query string from the $_POST array.  You might need to do something like that.

A tool  like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can be a useful tool in testing/debugging the code you will write.

Answer (score 0):

URL A:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['processed'])){
    $_SESSION['request'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('location: URL-B');
    exit;
}
```

URL B:

```
// do stuff
$_SESSION['processed'] = 1;
header('location: '.$_SESSION['request']);
exit;
```

something like that, anyway.

Comment: Will this work if there are POST values being passed in the original request? I'm not sure what the original request will contain.

Comment: You can set the post in the session as well, process on URL B, unset it and return to URL A.

Comment: How would I do that? I want to be able to receive the values in the $_POST variable in URL B.

Comment: URL A: `$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;` URL B: `$_POST = $_SESSION['post']; unset($_SESSION['post']);`

Comment: Ok, so this is not actually sending along the "exact request", correct? Its really using the $_SESSION variable to persist data. Correct?

Comment: Right. It's a copy of $_POST in $_SESSION. If you don't remove it (unset) from session it will persist as long as the session does.